# Syncronize mails with Exchangelib's "sync_item" doesn't work second time

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm using ExchangeLib to access my Mailbox and create some kind of a mail listener:

```
# Register and create inbox object
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=mail,
                                   credentials=credentials,
                                   config=config)
inbox=account.inbox
subscriptionId = inbox.subscribe_to_streaming(event_types=[NewMailEvent.ELEMENT_NAME])

# define filters
only=["subject", "body", "datetime_sent", "attachments", "sender"]

while True:
    for notification in inbox.get_streaming_events(
            subscriptionId, connection_timeout=30):
        # Retrieve mails via item id and changekey
        mailList = [inbox.get(id=event.item_id.id,
                              changekey=event.item_id.changekey)
                    for event in notification.events]
```

When I run this it works perfectly the first time the sync_items is called. The second time however (when the get_streaming_events notifies about new elements) it's quite unreliable and a lot of times I'm unable to retrieve mail items via `mailItems[sync[1] for sync in syncGenerator]`.

My initial approach was to add syncState in order to avoid ignoring mails by calling sync_items multiple time by accident and not returning anything. This however didn't solve the issue. I also experimented with `max_changes_returned=1` to exclude the problem of a too large amount of mails.

I would appreciate suggestions on whether I'm making any mistakes using `sync_items` or if I should use another way of accessing the mails.

Thanks a lot!

Edit 1: I replaced the use of `inbox.sync_items()` with the `inbox.get()` functionality. However, this is stuck as well.

Edit 2: I checked in a more general sense. Accessing the `inbox`mails via `inbox.filter(some_filter)` is possible before `get_streaming_events` but somehow not afterwards. Maybe the issue could be connected to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription sync (`Folder.get_streaming_events()`) and item sync (`Folder.sync_items()`) are two entirely different sync strategies and should not be combined. The former returns notification objects containing item IDs that you can use to look up the full object (`inbox.get(id=some_id, changekey=some_changekey)`).

The exchangelib documentation has full examples of using either strategy: https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#synchronization-subscriptions-and-notifications

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks so much for your response! I replaced the inbox.sync_items() just as you suggested (see adjusted question). However, this gets stuck as well. Is there any reason why this could be the case or might it just be a setup issue on my side?

Comment: I suspect that it gets stuck due to running out of connections. This is also described in the docs: ".get_streaming_events() occupies a connection to the server while it’s streaming events. If you need to do additional calls to the server while streaming, e.g. fetching extra item fields, moving items to a folder, sending emails etc, you need to make sure that you have enough connections to do so. The default configuration is to only have 1 connection. See the documentation on Configuration.max_connections on how to increase the connection count."

Comment: I did some research, going through the code that you wrote and it seems that when using Autodiscover it's not simply possible to alter the amount of max_connections. I also read this page "https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#optimizing-connections" but the examples there refer to autodiscover=False. I was wondering if there's a possibility to change the max_connections even after having created the "Account" object?

Comment: Ah. That's an oversight. Fixed in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/commit/568dc452339512675c2ae556b861a6057b8a212f Until it's released, you can do this: "account.protocol._session_pool_maxsize = 2"